# Map phpMyAdmin to a port on CentOS and Apache

Tags: apache, centos

I was wondering how I would go about setting up the virtual hosts so that I just have to enter www.mydomain.com:9090 to go to phpmyadmin.  This is how I have my vhosts set up right now in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This does not seem to be working.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot! I recently started using Amazon EC2 and I had the EC2 firewall bloking all ports except for the standard ones.  As soon as I enabled it everything started working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding... `Listen 9090` to your config?

Comment: Yes, I have Listen 9090 in the httpd.conf file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new Virtual host in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/localhost.conf` and then edit `httpd.conf` in `/etc/httpd/` to listen to new port. Restart httpd and then opened the port in IPtables. Apply the new rules.